# how to find multiple strings using range.value?

Tags: excel, vba

i tried to use range("A1:I1").value to find multiple strings at the first row however it shows that error "mismatch". What have i done wrong here? Is there another way to do it?

[image]

```
Dim sht as worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")

If sht.range("A1:I1").value = " Voltage" and sht.range("A1:I1").value = " Time"     ,<---------error 'mismatch' occurs here  

call powerandtime
```

Comment: You are comparing an array against a single value. That would return a type mismatch error. What exactly are you trying here? Do you want to know if both values occur in the array?

Comment: @JvdV ah i see, how do i use array in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are comparing an array of values against a single value. In case of such a small array you can make use of some `Application.Methods`. Another option would be to use `Range.Find` on the actual `Range` object. I'll demonstrate both below:

---

***<sub>Application.Methods</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")
Dim arr As Variant

With Application
    arr = .Transpose(ws.Range("A1:I1").Value)
    If .Count(.Match(Array("Voltage", "Time"), arr, 0)) = 2 Then
        Call PowerAndTime
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

What happens here is that `.Match` will return an array of two elements. It will either return an error value to the array if either "voltage" or "time" is not found, or it would return a numeric value when either one of them is found. Then `.Count` will count numeric values within that returned array, and only if the count would be 2, is when both values are present within your initial range.

**Note:** `.Match` needs a 1D-array, hence the `.Transpose` at the start.

---

***<sub>Range.Find</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = ws.Range("A1:I1").Find("Voltage", lookat:=xlWhole)
Set rng2 = ws.Range("A1:I1").Find("Time", lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing And Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    Call PowerAndTime
End If

End Sub
```

So only when both "Voltage" and "Time" are found as `xlWhole` values within your specific range, it would continue to call `PowerAndTime`.

Comment: your array method works well with my code, thanks alot. Anyways can i ask you some basic question like why with application is needed when using array? I tried to use array just now without the application and it does not works until i seen your post and then i realized it is needed.

Comment: Lets say  If .Count(.Match(Array("Voltage", "Time"), arr, 0)) = 3 or =4, does it  still means both values are still present within my initial range?

Comment: That will never happen. You are comparing an array of two values against `arr`. So either the return is 0, 1 or 2. And `Application` is needed since we basically using two worksheetfunctions, but the `Application` ensures that it wouldn't give you a run-time error.

Comment: oh ya can i also ask what does the 0 here means in Count(.Match(Array("Voltage", "Time"), arr, 0)) ?

Comment: @cena, that's the match_type parameter of the [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function which determines that we only want **exact** matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testMatchBis()
Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, voltPos As Long, timePos As Long
Dim rngBis As Range, arrBis as Variant

 Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use please your sheet here
 Set rng = sh.Range("A1:I1")
 voltPos = IsMatch(rng, "Voltage")
 timePos = IsMatch(rng, "Time")
 If voltPos <> 0 And timePos <> 0 Then
    Set rngBis = sh.Columns(voltPos)
    Set rngBis = Union(rngBis, sh.Columns(timePos))
    arrBis = rngBis.Value 'the both columns content will be input in an array
    rngBis.Select 'both columns will be selected. Of course, you need to determine
         'only part of the comumn keeping values (their last row) and limit the range
    'Call call powerandtime 'You must know what this sub must do...
 Else
    MsgBox "(At least) one of your searched strings could not be found in the range..."
 End If
End Sub

    Private Function IsMatch(rng As Range, strS As String) As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        IsMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(strS, rng, 0)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
            IsMatch = 0
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim arrStrings As Variant
    Dim i As Long, Counter As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I1")
    Counter = 0

    arrStrings = Split("Time,Electric", ",")

    For i = LBound(arrStrings) To UBound(arrStrings)

        If Not rng.Find(arrStrings(i), lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

            Counter = Counter + 1
            GoTo NextIteration

        End If

NextIteration:

    Next i

    If Counter = UBound(arrStrings) + 1 Then

        Call PowerAndTime

    End If

End Sub
```